# Autocompletion not working for pass password manager in zsh in linux

Tags: zsh, password, autocomplete, tree, password-store

I already used `pass` program for password managing on MacOS with zsh (where the autocompletion worked flawlessly out of the box) and now trying to move on linux on a raspberry pi 4b 4GB, installed zsh and pass which work great. I just cannot make the autocompletion work with pass, and I have to type the whole path for the password location to retrieve it. How could I get the autocompletion working?

Answer (score 1):

Ironically, I had this same issue but going from Debian to MacOS. This,

[[pass] I can't make work the zsh autocomplete](https://password-store.zx2c4.narkive.com/cFpeWylP/pass-i-can-t-make-work-the-zsh-autocomplete)

ten year old mail archive points out the crux of the matter. If completions in `zsh` are not working then the [pass.zsh-completion](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/tree/src/completion/pass.zsh-completion) file is not in the right place or on the (right) path. It may be that it was not downloaded depending upon how you downloaded `pass`. For me, `sudo apt install pass` made autocompletion work out of the box in bash.

Furthermore, do completions for other commands, e. g., `git commi[TAB]` work? If not then you need to enable them as I suspect they are not enabled by default in `zsh`. Try running `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit` and if that works then put it in your `.zshrc`.

If you installed pass using `brew install pass` then [you need to enable brew zsh completions](https://docs.brew.sh/Shell-Completion#configuring-completions-in-zsh) as they also aren't by default.